# Why doesn't the margin-bottom property work on my floated element?

Tags: html, css

I want the `<h1>` and `<p>` elements in the header to be appear on the right side of the page and to be a little higher up. How can I do this? I've tried everything I can think of, I'm not sure what to do.

```css
/* Global */
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Header */
header {
    background: #ec1480;
    padding: 65px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid pink;
}

header #branding {
    float: right;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

header a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: pink;
}

header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta name="description" content="blog template">
        <meta name="keywords" content="blog template">
        <meta name="author" content="#">
        <title>Blog | Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./stylesheets/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="branding">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                </div>                    
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
       
        <section class="posts">
            <article>
                <h2>Blogger Introduction Post</h2>
                <img src="./images/blog-post.jpg">
            </article>
        </section>
        
        <aside id="sidebar">
            <div id="share">
               <h3>Share this page</h3>
               <a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank"><button>Facebook</button></a>
               <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><button>Twitter</button></a>
               <a href="https://pinterest.com" target="_blank"><button>Pinterest</button></a>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please use CSS Flexbox Layout module**

I corrected your code.

Just add CSS :-

```
header #container{display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;}
```

You need to change sequence of `menu` and `<div id="branding">`

```
 <div id="container">                                    
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div id="branding">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Updated snippet :**

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Header */
header {
    background: #ec1480;
    padding: 65px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid pink;
}

header #branding {
    float: right;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

header a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: pink;
}

header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

header #container{display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;}
```

```html
 <body>
        <header>
            <div id="container">                                    
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div id="branding">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
       
        <section class="posts">
            <article>
                <h2>Blogger Introduction Post</h2>
                <img src="./images/blog-post.jpg">
            </article>
        </section>
        
        <aside id="sidebar">
            <div id="share">
               <h3>Share this page</h3>
               <a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank"><button>Facebook</button></a>
               <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><button>Twitter</button></a>
               <a href="https://pinterest.com" target="_blank"><button>Pinterest</button></a>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </body>
```

Comment: and container is an id not a class